# Who were the inshi in shaas?

Tags: torah-study, talmud-gemara

Many times in shaas we find Amoraim saying כדאמרי אינשי or היינו דאמרי אינשי. Usually its brought as a proof for something said but once in a while it is used as a question והא אמרי אינשי.

Are the baalei shaas quoting anyone in particular? Were these just folk sayings? Should the colloquial expressions really play such an important part in deciding halacha, either to prove or disprove it?

Answer (score 5):

I once spoke to R' Tzvi Berkowitz about this idea.  He explained that this is not a source proof, but a reverse indication.  I.e. if people say a certain thing, there is an underlying cause to why it became an accepted and understood assumption, and the point under discussion is a [possible] source of where this common understanding developed from.

The Talmud is not quoting anyone in particular - it is quoting common knowledge.  It is not being used as proof or a source, but is being used as an after-the-fact indication of such a thing being true, as it would explain the emergence of said common knowledge.

Comment: What's the difference between a proof and an indication? That the former is incontrovertible? The Gemara reinterprets Tannaitic statements all the time so it's hard to call them incontrovertible.

Comment: @DoubleAA That it was not the authority of the "inshi" that produced the halacha - they are an indication to its existence, not the authority that produced it.  סימן ולא סיבה

Comment: This is the pshat I used to hear in yeshiva and besides the circular logic involved, it doesn't answer how we can bring an amri inshi as a question on a pshat or as an astand alone proof.

Comment: @user6591 Why is it circular?  It does not rest on any of its conclusions.  Why does it not explain how it could be a question?  It is an indication to the acceptance of a certain line of logic.

Comment: Then maybe I'm just not understanding. Are we assuming the source of the logic to be the talmudic Rabbis? Then the fact that its a popular saying shouldn't really matter should it?

Comment: @user6591 I don't have every use of the phrase at my fingertips, but the significance will vary contextually. If the Rabbis of now are disputing what the Rabbis of then held, then it is an indication what the Rabbis of then held.

Comment: K. Hold on. Are we assuming the 'inshi' are people in the beis medrash or out in the streets?

Comment: @user6591 I assume their geographical location doesn't matter.  It means "what people say" - common saying.  Not what someone said in the beis medrash as part of the discussion currently going on.

Comment: So then why would we be quoting it? Every folk saying was believed to have talmudic roots?

Comment: @user6591 Something which is accepted as common knowledge is assumed to have come from somewhere.  It's not infallible, but it is an indication.

Comment: But that somewhere is not necessarily a good source. Im sorry if im repeating myself but I don't understand how the knowledge as described can be used to question something an Amorah said.

Comment: @user6591 in deciding between two options, it makes one of them more reasonable.  This whole concept may be hard, because we all know what we know because it says so in a sefer somewhere or a Rabbi taught us.  But once upon a time, Judaism was learned organically, and Jewish wisdom was not exclusively contained in the books.

Comment: That sounds like a pshat I was hoping someone would say or (quote from somewhere :) but it doesn't sound the same as the pshat from R' Berkowitz, is it?

Comment: Here are the instances that really bug me. Brachos 59a, B.K. 11a, B.M. 59a, Chulin 58b & 97b. Also you'll notice a trend that cought my attention, a tremendous amount of all the amri inshi in shas is quoted by Rav Papa. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @user6591 I think that is what R' Berkowitz meant - the Jewish people were a depository of Jewish wisdom, and therefore their common sayings are indicative of Jewish values.

Answer (score 1):

I've always learned this as "the people say", i.e. folk sayings.